# What does "\r" do in the following script?

Tags: python, telnet

I am using following script to reboot my router using Telnet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import telnetlib
from time import sleep

host = "192.168.1.1"
user = "USER"
password = "PASSWORD"
cmd = "system restart"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
sleep(1)

tn.read_until("Login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n\r")
sleep(1)

tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n\r")
sleep(1)

tn.write(cmd + "\n\r")
```

I don't know why but removing `"\r"` breaks this code. So what does `"\r"` do in this script and when do I use `"\r"` in general?

Note: I know about "Carriage Return" but still could not figure out it is used in my script. I am running this script in Linux.

Comment: It's a [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Comment: I used google to read everything about carriage return but still could not figure out its use in my above script.

Comment: i suggest you also take look at : http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/ref/strings.html which explains all escape characters

Comment: This question may have been asked also because of what printing just an \r character does not do, which is advance the line.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `'\r'` character is the carriage return, and the carriage return-newline pair is both needed for newline in a network virtual terminal session.

---

From the [old telnet specification (RFC 854)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) (page 11):

> The sequence "CR LF", as defined, will cause the NVT to be
> positioned at the left margin of the next print line (as would,
> for example, the sequence "LF CR").

However, from the [latest specification (RFC5198)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198) (page 13):

> 1. ...
> 2. In Net-ASCII, CR MUST NOT appear except when immediately followed
>    by either NUL or LF, with the latter (CR LF) designating the "new
>    line" function.  Today and as specified above, CR should
>    generally appear only when followed by LF.  Because page layout
>    is better done in other ways, because NUL has a special
>    interpretation in some programming languages, and to avoid other
>    types of confusion, CR NUL should preferably be avoided as
>    specified above.
> 3. LF CR SHOULD NOT appear except as a side-effect of multiple CR LF
>    sequences (e.g., CR LF CR LF).

So newline in Telnet should always be `'\r\n'` but most implementations have either not been updated, or keeps the old `'\n\r'` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yeah great, but notice how he uses NL CR instead of CR NL... ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker `"\r\n"` is the traditional version, but the other way around works as well.

Comment: ;) Just wanted to make this clear; the OP seems to be unaware of EOL requirements...

Answer (score 24):

`'\r'` means 'carriage return' and it is similar to `'\n'` which means 'line break' or more commonly 'new line'

in the old days of typewriters, you would have to move the carriage that writes back to the start of the line, and move the line down in order to write onto the next line.

in the modern computer era we still have this functionality for multiple reasons. but mostly we use only `'\n'` and automatically assume that we want to start writing from the start of the line, since it would not make much sense otherwise.

however, there are some times when we want to use JUST the `'\r'` and that would be if i want to write something to an output, and the instead of going down to a new line and writing something else, i want to write something over what i already wrote, this is how many programs in linux or in windows command line are able to have 'progress' information that changes on the same line.

nowadays most systems use only the `'\n'` to denote a newline. but some systems use both together.

you can see examples of this given in some of the other answers, but the most common are:

- windows ends lines with `'\r\n'`
- mac ends lines with `'\r'`
- unix/linux use `'\n'`

and some other programs also have specific uses for them.

for more information about the [history of these characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History)

Comment: sorry, but don't agree. It is the TELNET protocol itself which requires `\r\n` (defined as the end-of-line sequence in the protocol). See [RFC854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854).

Comment: @isedev i am not sure how your comment relates to my answer. i think you commented to the wrong answer, or please explain yourself further.

Comment: Still, I say it's \r\n that is [defined](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/31.htm), despite the fact that \n\r also works.

Comment: @Inbar: just mean it has nothing to do with operating system in this case. It is defined by TELNET protocol spec, independently of OS.

Comment: @isedev did i say it did? you are giving criticism to a point that i did not even make?

Comment: @inbar: not as such, but I think your answer was misleading, mentioning differences between OS, when OS has nothing to do with it. Is that really so offensive?

Comment: @isedev what i wrote is 'you can see examples of this given in some of the other answers, but the most common are' im just summarizing the answers given by other users so as to make a cohesive answer.

Comment: @InbarRose 
A little of topic but regarding your comment \r is similar to \n.
I think they are different on (atleast linux I guess).
check out the example :

`print "bbb\raaaa" # output : aaaa`
`print "__bbb\raaaa" # output : aaaab`
`print "_____bbb\raaaa" # output : aaaa_bbb`

Here \r is signals end of line and the cursor moved to the start of line and subsequent characters are printed from there.

Answer (score 7):

`\r` is the ASCII [Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (CR) character.

There are different newline conventions used by different operating systems. The most common ones are:

- CR+LF (`\r\n`);
- LF (`\n`);
- CR (`\r`).

The `\n\r` (LF+CR) looks unconventional.

**edit:** My reading of the [Telnet RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) suggests that:

1. CR+LF is the standard newline sequence used by the telnet protocol.
2. LF+CR is an acceptable substitute:

> The sequence "CR LF", as defined, will cause the NVT to be
> positioned at the left margin of the next print line (as would,
> for example, the sequence "LF CR").

Comment: sorry, but don't agree. It is the TELNET protocol itself which requires `\r\n` (defined as the end-of-line sequence in the protocol). See [RFC854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854).

Comment: @isedev: I am seeing lots of mentions of `CR LF` in the RFC, and only one mention of `LF CR`. Could you point to a specific page/section?

Comment: Being dislexic, did mean the usual `\r\n`. Corrected comments and answer. My point was really it has nothing to do with OS, but TELNET protocol itself (i.e. required for TELNET on Linux and TELNET on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this has nothing to do with the usual Windows / Unix `\r\n` vs `\n` issue. The TELNET procotol itself defines `\r\n` as the end-of-line sequence, independently of the operating system. See [RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854).

Comment: Umm, no; TELNET defines CR LF aka \r\n as the eond-of-line sequence.

Comment: Everybody started teaching me about carriage return which i already know and started downvoting my question without answering. I think you are correct about Telnet.