# String splitlines() - problem with leading and trailing whitespace (hidden chars) that I'm unable to strip

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a 3 column file, an example posted below

```
P1\tTitle\tName
P2\tTitle\Name
```

etc.

The file itself does not have any leading spaces, or spaces between the columns.  But, when I use python's f.read().splitlines() and then print each line, I see each line printed with a leading and trailing space for each column/split.  If I then try to strip each of these variables using strip(), the spaces don't go away (which makes me think they are not spaces, but another hidden char).  I even tried regex to remove the space

```
re.sub(r'\W+', '', string)
```

But that did not work either.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: `splitlines()` doesn't introduce whitespace. Post some code and someone might be able to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The tabs will expand, is that what you mean? As a test, print `repr(string)` to see the tabs as `\t`.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you are expecting the string to be modified in place. You need to assign the result back to the string.

```
foo = foo.strip()
```

Here is an example of how you could split your data

```
>>> s = """P1\tTitle\tName
... P2\tTitle\tName"""
>>> for row in s.splitlines():
...     print row.split("\t")
... 
['P1', 'Title', 'Name']
['P2', 'Title', 'Name']
```

The `csv` module can be used to process `tvs` files too, so maybe it's more suitable for your file.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well, but it still seems to be adding the extra space like characters.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` character is the carriage return, and the carriage return-newline (`\n`) pair is both needed for newline in a network virtual terminal session. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606871/2119941).

So you can add to the end of your strings in your code  something like this:

```
.strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

so above solution would look like this

```
for row in s.splitlines():
    print row.split("\t").strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```