# How to add \\ in string with python

Tags: string, python-2.7, path

I want to get a path location as ' **\\BIWDB02\e$\research**' using `os.join.path`

I tried these ways

```
 import os
 a = 'BIWDB02'
 b = 'e$\research'
 c = '\\\\'
 print c
    # \\
```

**Try-1:**

```
x = os.path.join('\\','\\',a,b)
print x
```

output:

```
 \BIWDB02\e$
    esearch
```

Don't know why it is coming on next line and even 'r' is missing.

**Try-2 ,3**

```
y = os.path.join('\\\\',a,b)
print y

z= os.path.join(c,a,b)
print z
```

**Error:**

> IndexError: string index out of range

**Update:**

```
os.path.join('\\\\\\',a,b)
#\\\BIWDB02\e$\research
```

with 6-\\\ it gives me 3-\\ but with 4-\\ it gives me indexError again.

Comment: \r is a carriage return character; it tells your terminal emulator to move the cursor at the start of the line

Comment: define `b` as `b = r'e$\research'` and then just do `os.path.join(a,b)`. It should be enough

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) for more details about raw string literals.

Comment: I have updated my output: it should be \\ at start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is coming from the `\r` in `e$\research`. `\r` is know as a  [carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606799/what-does-r-do-in-the-following-script) and performs a return newline.

Add `r` to `e$\research` to make it a [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

```
import os
a = 'BIWDB02'
b = r'e$\research'
c = '\\\\'
x = os.path.join(c, a, b)
print x

>>> \\BIWDB02\e$\research
```

Comment: Thanks .. but I need \\ at start of string

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham I updated my answer. I noticed in your update, you said \\\\ gives you an `IndexError`. Which version of python are you running? I tested my update in 2.7 and 3.5 and I did not receive the error

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually escape your path names. You can cast them as raw strings in Python 2.x as follows:

```
"Path with lots of tricky characte\rs.\n..durr".encode('string-escape')
```