# Regex to find all backslashes and the immediately following character

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working with email data and when extracting from Outlook, the body of the email still keeps all of the escape characters within the string.

I'm using the `re` package in Python to achieve this, but to no avail.

Here's an example of text I'm trying to rid the escape characters from:

> I am completely in agreement with that. \r\n\r\n\rbest regards.

Expected:

> I'd like this to read: "I am completely in agreement with that. best
>   regards.

I've tried the following to extract the unwanted text:

```py
re.findall(r'\\\w+', string)
re.findall(r'\\*\w+', string)
re.findall(r'\\[a-z]+', string)
```

None of these are doing the trick. I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
re.sub(r'\n|\r','', string)


'I am completely in agreement with that. best regards.'
```

Comment: For Python 2.x and unicode strings it may be necessary to first compile the pattern with flag `re.UNICODE` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a representation of whitechars (please [read more about them here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606799/what-does-r-do-in-the-following-script)).

You should rather be looking for `\r`, `\n` characters this way:

```
re.findall(r'\n\w+', string)
```

or

```
re.findall(r'\r\w+', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get rid of the line returns. If so, you don't need the re module, just use:

```
string.replace("\r\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function by yourself:

```
def function(string):
    while '\\' in string:
        ind = string.find('\\')
        string = string[:ind] + string[ind+2:]

    return string
```