# why does the escape code '\r' cause the console to create a sub-console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am testing out the `print()` function and tried this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in range(3):
        print('\r',i,end='',file=sys.stdout)
```

I want the command to print 0 then 1 then 2 to the console each replacing the one before, but the result is an input request that looks like this:

```
2 >>>
```

why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Edit: better example

Comment: If you want to print "test" to the console, what's wrong with `print('test')`? I'm not sure what "fix it" means here. What did you expect?

Comment: Say I printed a line before, but want to remove it.

Comment: no need to use `file=sys.stdout` param, just use `print('test')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "\r" do in the following script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606799/what-does-r-do-in-the-following-script)

Comment: So `print('\rtest')` does what you want?

Comment: @Aran-Fey that does not work

Answer (score 3):

Consider a simpler example:

```
>>> print('test')
test
>>>
```

Now add `end=''` to suppress the newline:

```
>>> print('test', end='')
test>>>
```

Without the newline, the prompt is displayed *immediately* after the string `test`; the cursor was never moved to the next line.

Now add the carriage return:

```
>>> print('\r', 'test', end='')
 test>>>
```

The `\r` doesn't really do anything: it causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the current line, but the cursor is *already* there. However, `print` does output a space before printing the next string, and as before, no newline is printed to move the cursor to the next line.

Here's an example where `\r` *does* have an effect. Compare

```
>>> print('foo', 'bar', end='')
foo bar>>>
```

with

```
>>> print('123456789', '\r', 'bar', end='')
 bar>>> 9
```

`123456789` is printed, but the `\r` moves the cursor so that the space and `bar` overwrites the `1234`. The prompt and following space output by the interpreter itself overwrites `5678`.

Comment: but why exactly does it print `bar>>> ` to the console and not just `bar`?

Comment: The `>>>` is part of the next prompt for the interpretter. Because you specified `end = ""`, the cursor will be at the end of your string and that's where the prompt will go. If you want it to appear on the next line (probably like you are accustomed to) then you need to print a final new line, which puts the cursor at the start of the next line.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question