# What Is the Use Of ( \r ) carriage return in python program?

Tags: python

I wrote,

```
print('C:\docs\rohit')
>>> C:\docsohit
```

You see rohit is my name but in result, I got **docssohit**
well basically it moves a sentence toward left but in my case specifically in IDLE it is
giving something else.
IDLE 3.8.0

Comment: IDLE does not properly handle `\r`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "\r" do in the following script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606799/what-does-r-do-in-the-following-script)

Answer (score 0):

[Python IDLE does not properly handle control charcaters like `\r`,`b` etc.](https://bugs.python.org/issue23220). Use Python console interpreter (`python.exe`,`python3.exe`) instead.

Comment: Yeah it definitely seems like that, I will.Thnxs

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio and install the python addons instead.

Comment: Yeah i do use visual studio and pycharm, George. its just that i wanted to experience some basics.TBH i am still NOOB