# Why does using a \r when calling django templates in views result in error?

Tags: django

I'm creating a view from my Django app that's suppose to call a template in my app directory called rooms. My app's name is room. When I write the code

```
return render(request, 'base\room.html', context)
```

I get an error at \r and the page doesn't load. Mind you, changing the template name to anything other than it starting without an r works fine. So, 'base\loom.html' works. Any idea why this is so? I only started noticing this recently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "\r" do in the following script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606799/what-does-r-do-in-the-following-script)

Comment: Just use forward slashes `'base/room.html'`

Comment: Forward slashes did the trick. I didn't know if it would work with forward slashes so I never tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you inherited room.html with base.html then go with this code

```
return render(request, 'room.html', context)
```

if you have not inherited room.html with base.html then go with this code

```
return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

Comment: Because the template this is referring to is in the app's template directory, using just 'room.html' won't work. But using forward slashes fixed the issue for me. Thanks!